# How to refer to multiple classes without creating a mess?

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I have 8 steps (think of it as a wizard). Each step consists of something different so I've created 8 classes. Each of the classes need some information from the previous steps (classes). All the classes are called from one main class. The neatiest way I've found to handle this situation is :

```
public void Main()
{
   var step1 = new Step1();
   step1.Process();
   var step2 = new Step2(step1);
   step2.Process();
   var step3 = new Step3(step1, step2);
   //...
   var step8 = new Step8(step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6, step7);
   step8.Process();
}
```

Obviously, this is a mess. I don't want to send that many parameters and I don't want to use static classes (probably not a good practice).

How would you handle such situation?

Comment: are your classes in separate .cs files or nested in one single namespace..? I just did something close to what you are talking about and I created Auto property's in one or both of my classes and uses a smart way of passing / assigning steps and it looks really clean can you show what the class names / structure look like..

Comment: Same namespace, but different .cs files

Comment: Chain of Responsibility pattern?

Comment: that's also fine.. based on what you have .. lets say it's a console application.. you can come up with a smart way of handling Steps as you have called them.. it's just a matter of how you set up the Constructors in those classes to allow overloads / Params.. does this make sense..?

Comment: You can also take a look at the [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx) pattern

Comment: are the steps Int32, boolean, or MethodName as strings..?

Comment: Mathieu I agree with Oleksii take a look at the link it looks really close to what you are trying to attempt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds to me like something that you could accomplish via a [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility_pattern). That is the direction that I would look into at least.

If you go down that path, then you will leave yourself open to a cleaner implementation of adding/removing steps in the future.

And, as far as the multiple data sets, John Koerner is correct in that you should have one data model that is updated in each step. This will allow you to implement a clean chain of responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

Have a single class that is your datamodel that can be used throughout the processes.  The steps update their piece of the datamodel and that is the only object passed to each subsequent step.

Answer (score 1):

Create just one class and use different methods as steps

```
class Wizard
{
    int someIntInfo;
    string some StringInfo;
    ...

    public void ProcessStep1();
    public void ProcessStep2();
    public void ProcessStep3();
    public void ProcessStep4();
}
```

Or create a step and an info interface and declare the wizard like this by passing the same info to all steps

```
interface IWizardInfo
{
    int someIntInfo { get set; }
    string someStringInfo { get set; }
    ...
}

interface IStep
{
    void Process(IWizardInfo info);
}

class Wizard
{
     IWizardInfo _info = ....;
     IStep[] _steps = new IStep[] { new Step1(), new Step2(), ... };
     int _currentStep;

     void ProcessCurrentStep()
     {
         _steps[_currentStep++].Process(_info);
     }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Create a compound class which can hold all previous steps

```
class Step1 { public Step1(AllSteps steps) { steps.Step1 = this; } ... }
class Step2 { public Step2(AllSteps steps) { steps.Step2 = this; } ... }
class Step3 { public Step3(AllSteps steps) { steps.Step3 = this; } ... }

class AllSteps
{
     public Step1 Step1 { get; set; }
     public Step2 Step2 { get; set; }
     public Step3 Step3 { get; set; }
}
```

Pass the same info to all steps. The steps are responsible to add themselves to the info

```
AllSteps allSteps = new AllSteps();
var stepX = new StepX(allSteps);
```

Comment: Could be good if I had less substeps. In this case, it would create a 3-4k line file with tens of properties

Comment: Added a solution, which basically does what you did initially; however, instead of passing all the steps one by one as parameter, it uses a class which puts all the steps together.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create one single class for all of your steps and implement state management within that class? e.g.

```
private class Steps
{
   private int _stepIndex = 0;
   public void Process()
   {
       switch(_stepIndex)
       {
          case 0: // First Step
             ...  // Perform business logic for step 1.
             break;
          case 1: // Second Step
             ...  // Perform business logic for step 2.
             break;
       }
       _stepIndex++;
   }
}
```

Comment: That is good when steps are simples. On larger steps, though, this becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Java's inner classes are better suited for this than anything C# has. But, C# is so much better in so many other aspects, we'll let this one pass.

You should create one class that contains all your data. If your steps are simple, you should have one method per step in that one class. If your steps are complicated, separate them into classes, but give each of them access to the data class.

Answer (score 1):

You can have interface IProcess with method `Run(Wizard)` and property `Name`, several processes and everyone inherits IProcess, and class Wizard that contain processes to run in the list. So:

```
class Wizard
{
    private IList<IProcess> processes = new List<IProcess();

    public T GetProcess<T>(string name) 
           where T : IProcess
    {
        return (T)processes.Single(x => x.Name == name);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
       foreach (var proc in processes) 
              proc.Run(this);
    }
}
```

Every process can have access to the wizard using argument of the Run method, or just have it in the constructor. By calling `wizard.GetProcess<Process1>("some name")` you can have your process that was previously executed (you can add a check).

Other option is to contain results in the `Wizard` class.

This is only one of many variants. You can look at Chain of Responsibility Pattern, like Justin suggests

Answer (score 1):

I would say a classical example for a variation of a [Chain-Of-Responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
class Request
{
    private List<string> _data;

    public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
    {
        return _data.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public string AddData(string value)
    {
        _data.Add(value);
    }
}

abstract class Step
{
    protected Step _nextStep;

    public void SetSuccessor(Step step)
    {
        _nextStep = step;
    }

    public abstract void Process(Request request);
}

sealed class Step1 : Step
{
    public override void Process(Request request)
    {
        var data = request.GetData();

        Console.Write("Request processed by");
        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0} ", datum);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now is my turn!");

        request.AddData("step1");

        _nextStep.Process(request);
    }
}

// Other steps omitted.
sealed class Step8 : Step
{
    public override void Process(Request request)
    {
        var data = request.GetData();

        Console.Write("Request processed by");
        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0} ", datum);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Guess we're through, huh?");
    }
}

void Main()
{
     var step1 = new Step1();
     // ...
     var step8 = new Step8();
     step8.SetSuccessor(step1);

     var req = new Request();
     step1.Process(req);
}
```

Comment: Nice example! I'll give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

I would have two ArrayLists (or depending on your class and method structure they might be simple Lists) - one for methods (as delegates) and one for results.

So, foreach method would go through delegates and invoke them with results list as parameter (you might accommodate your methods to accept such parametars and work with them) and add result to results list.